# Why does MKMapView.cameraZoomRange differ from MKMapCamera.centerCoordinateDistance when zooming to max/min?

Tags: ios, mapkit

If you set up the `cameraZoomRange` of an `MKMapView` and then check in `mapView(_:regionDidChangeAnimated:)`, when hitting either the min and max centre distance, the `centerCoordinateDistance` of the `MKMapView.camera` is off by a factor of ≈1.55.

In other words, when setting up the `MKMapView`:

```swift
mapView.cameraZoomRange = MKMapView.CameraZoomRange(
    minCenterCoordinateDistance: 2500)
```

And then in the delegate callback:

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    print("camera distance \(mapView.camera.centerCoordinateDistance) m")
}
```

This reports values in the range ≈1610.3788 to ≈1615.5012 depending on the device you are running on, which I guess is due to the different screen sizes.

This API was introduced in iOS 13, and I get this behaviour on iOS 14 as well.